# Unable to locate package industrial

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-industrial, ur5, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to setup a connection to an UR5. I use Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) with ROS Indigo. I followed the tutrioal [Getting Started with a Universal Robot and ROS-Industrial](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial#Using_MoveIt.21_with_hardware). There it's said that I need the ROS-Industrial's industrial_core package. Therefore I followed the [Industrial/Install](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Install)-tutorial. But when trying the commands

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-industrial-core
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-industrial-desktop
```

I get the error

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-industrial-desktop
```

I also tried the other steps of the [Getting Started with a Universal Robot and ROS-Industrial](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial#Using_MoveIt.21_with_hardware) but then I get the Error

```
[FATAL] [1424787993.220925675]: Exception while loading controller manager 'moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager': According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager with base class type movit_controller_manager::MoveItControllerManager does not exitst.
```

I guess that's then part of the Ros-Industrial-Package?

Any help is appreciated. Please consider, that I'm a real beginner in ROS.

Thanks and regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203699/unable-to-locate-package-industrial/) by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You forgot to add it to your question, but I guess you are running Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) with ROS Indigo?

The ROS-Industrial packages have not yet been released for Indigo, *except* those from the Universal Robots repository. So you cannot install `industrial-desktop` on Indigo yet.

In addition, you cannot install `ros-hydro-x-x` packages on Ubuntu Trusty, as Hydro is not supported on Trusty.

Try installing the Universal Robot packages like this:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-universal-robot
```

that *should* work.

PS: You don't need `industrial_core` for the Universal Robot packages. That is only needed for the other drivers in ROS-Industrial. I've logged an issue about that ([universal_robot/issues/173](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/173)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-02-24**:
It works exactly as you wrote. Thanks for the information!! :)

And yes you're right about my Ubuntu and ROS versions as well.

Thanks again!!